# Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter, android-gradle-plugin, twitter-fabric

```
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:0.8.0@aar')
        {
            transitive = true;
        }
```

i got gradle from [https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/compose](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/compos)

But when Sync the Android Studio project following error is coming ..

Error:(53, 13) **Failed to resolve: **com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:0.8.0****
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Comment: I think you need to use 
 maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

as is explain in this link:
https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/android/integrating

Comment: iGoda ,so i  need to create fabric account for that ???

Comment: buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to
    // react quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 
//Put Fabric plugin after Android plugin
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
 
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}      where  will add ?? in root Project gradle ???

Comment: Yes I belive so, in order to user the different components that twitter makes available you have to setup the fabric io plugin.

Comment: @user3616253 in your module build.gradle.

Answer (score 7):

As was described on twitter, you have to change some parts in your module `build.gradle`.

In your module you can use:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to
    // react quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//Put Fabric plugin after Android plugin
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

I suggest you installing the Android Studio [plugin](https://fabric.io/downloads).

It helps you to configure the gradle script.

Answer (score 0):

This help me
https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/installation

```
 dependencies {
 // Include all the Twitter APIs
 compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'
 // (Optional) Monetize using mopub
 compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.0.0'
}
```

OR

```
enter code dependencies {
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0'
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.0.0'
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.0.0'
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.0.0'
}
```