# How to use Twitter API in APP

Tags: android, twitter, sdk, twitter-fabric

I'm following this tutorial so I could integrate it so I to let the user compose a tweet and post it; https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/compose-tweets.html 
But I can't seem to get pass the first part.

When I add the following in my build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

I get the following error: ***Failed to resolve com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.3***

I'm guessing there's a step before I missed? I have a Consumer Key (API Key) and consumer secret

Comment: I think Gabriele already addressed a solution for this. Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31001693/5885018

Comment: [check this](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html)